# MySQL - sum most common number from each col, show results where sum of col is between 185 and 215

Tags: mysql, numbers, sum, between

I have the following sql queries setup for my PowerBall game.  I had to split it into 2 queries because the PowerBall number has to be queried separately.

What I need help with is how I can sum up all the columns (NoA, NoB, NoC, NoD, NoE and NoPB) and have it display the most common set of 6 numbers where the total of all the columns is between 185 and 215.

As an example scenario, let's say the top random numbers are: 1, 10, 30, 15, 6 and 20.  The sum of that is 82.  I don't want that to show up since the sum of all the columns isn't between 185 and 215.

Here's the code snippet I have so far:

```
<code>
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT NoA, COUNT(*) AS Occurences FROM
(SELECT NoA FROM Numbers
UNION ALL
SELECT NoB FROM Numbers
UNION ALL
SELECT NoC FROM Numbers
UNION ALL
SELECT NoD FROM Numbers
UNION ALL
SELECT NoE FROM Numbers) t
GROUP BY NoA
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
LIMIT 5;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<tr>" . $row['NoA'] . "&nbsp;</tr>";
echo "<tr>" . $row['NoB'] . "&nbsp;</tr>";
echo "<tr>" . $row['NoC'] . "&nbsp;</tr>";
echo "<tr>" . $row['NoD'] . "&nbsp;</tr>";
echo "<tr>" . $row['NoE'] . "&nbsp;</tr>";
}
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT NoPB, COUNT(*) AS Occurences
FROM Numbers
GROUP BY NoPB
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
LIMIT 1;");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{ 
echo "<font style='color: #FF0000;'><tr>" . $row2['NoPB'] . "</tr><br /><br /></font>";
}
</code>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jerome

Comment: What do you mean by "display the most common set of 6 numbers"?

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in FROM clause sums the "No*" columns and limits results to between 185 and 215, then the main query groups the sums, counts the like sums, order descending then limits to the largest 6.

```
SELECT snum, count(*) AS cc
    FROM (
        SELECT NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB AS snum
            FROM Numbers
            WHERE NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB > 185 
              AND NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB < 215
    ) AS subnumquery
    GROUP BY snum
    ORDER BY cc DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```

Gives me:

```
+------+----+
| snum | cc |
+------+----+
|  209 |  3 |
|  206 |  2 |
|  207 |  1 |
|  192 |  1 |
+------+----+
```

How close does that get you to your goal?

Or is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT CONCAT(NoA, ',', NoB, ',', NoC, ',', NoD, ',', NoE, ',', NoPB) AS allnum
    , sumnum, count(*) AS cc
    FROM (
        SELECT NoA, NoB, NoC, NoD, NoE, NoPB, 
            NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB AS sumnum
            FROM Numbers
            WHERE NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB > 185 
              AND NoA + NoB + NoC + NoD + NoE + NoPB < 215
    ) AS subnumquery
    GROUP BY allnum
    ORDER BY cc DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```

Gives me:

```
+-----------------+--------+----+
| allnum          | sumnum | cc |
+-----------------+--------+----+
| 6,8,3,77,32,83  |    209 |  3 |
| 9,9,50,61,39,38 |    206 |  2 |
| 2,26,7,53,28,76 |    192 |  1 |
| 57,52,2,3,10,83 |    207 |  1 |
+-----------------+--------+----+
```

Here's my test DB setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (
  `NoA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoD` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoPB` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Numbers` VALUES (28,15,30,73,82,37),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(6,8,3,77,32,83),(81,80,14,5,83,92),(9,9,50,61,39,38),(33,9,15,6,27,92),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(6,8,3,77,32,83),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(57,52,2,3,10,83),(33,9,15,6,27,92),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(28,15,30,73,82,37),(75,16,2,45,20,83),(9,9,50,61,39,38),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(33,9,15,6,27,92),(2,26,7,53,28,76),(77,34,11,56,20,83),(51,74,28,14,28,93),(6,8,3,77,32,83),(33,9,15,6,27,92),(51,74,28,14,28,93);
```

Comment: I think this would work for the first 5 numbers (change it to LIMIT 5).  How would I include the NoPB column for the 6th number?  Many thanks for your help so far bK!

Comment: I can't say I'm entirely clear what your objective is. If this doesn't do it, please elaborate.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not being clear enough bK.  What I'm hoping to do is view the row with the most occurences where all the numbers added up is between 185 and 215.  It's just a nice to have thing.

Jerome

Comment: No sweat. Maybe it's me, but I'm still fuzzy. How about this, does the response I wrote do what you're looking for? Or part of what you're looking for? If not, please describe what works, what doesn't, and what is missing.

Comment: The latest two don't appear to run?  Just shows a blank page.  I did set the limit to 6 to include the NoPB column.  I like what you did there, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working, odd.

Jerome

Comment: `LIMIT` affects the number of rows returned, not the number of columns included in each row.